# Is this a good approach for api clone (api scraping)?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, mapreduce

currently I am working with a pipeline node.js base with backpressure in order to download all data from several API endpoints, some of these endpoints have data related between them.

The idea is to make a refactor in order to build an application more maintainable than the current in order to improve the updates over the data, and the current approach is the following.

The first step (map) is to download all data from endpoints and push into several topics, some of this data is complex and it is necessary data from one endpoint in order to retrieve data from another endpoint.

And the second step (reduce) is to get that data from all topics and push into a SQL but only the data that we need.

The question are

- Could be a good approach to this problem
- Is better to use Kafka streams in order to use KSQL to make transforms and only use a microservice to publish into the database.

The architecture schema is the following, and real time is not necessary for this data:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What issues are you having so far? You can use Kafka Connect for sourcing API data and sinking to a database. Or you can replace the source with KafkaJS producer... Kafka Streams is not required, but it can be used if needed

Comment: Currently I have problems loading data in the node.js pipeline, and backpresure doesn't work.
The code estructure is not the best.
If I can test i need run al the pipeline.

Comment: I don't really know nodejs all that well, but I would assume `rxjs` library, for example, might be able to help with that

Comment: Take a look at Scramjet Transform Hub (`@scramjet/sth`) - you can use this to create a generator and acquire the data more or less as you described it above. [I'm the author BTW].